# GET request that triggers PATCH request (express)

Tags: api, express

On my express server I have a script which retrieves items through scraping. I want to trigger this script once in a while and push the retrieved items into my database.

My first ideas was to create an endpoint in my API (e.g. /api/scrape-items). The problem is that it would be a GET request responsible for running the script, retrieving the items *AND* PATCH the items (update) my database. It doesn't seem right to let a GET request do all of that, especially to make a PATCH request, but I can't change the GET request to a POST request either because I have no body.

Can someone help me come up with a better approach? Thanks!

**UPDATE: Example of triggering endpoint:**

```js
router.get('/scrape-items/', async (req, res) => {
      try {
        const resultFromScraping = await [
          { id: 1, data: 'updated data' },
          { id: 2, data: 'updated data' }
        ]
        await Promise.all(
          resultFromScraping.map(
            async item =>
              await axios.patch(
                `/api/items/${item.id}`,
                item.data
              )
          )
        )
      } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: err.message })
      }
    })
```

Comment: A body is not required for a post request

Comment: @NicholasSiegmundt I am actually using patch, does it only apply for post? Do you think it is fine for a post endpoint to retrieve extrenal stuff and update the db? Does it apply for patch as well?

Comment: Patch is usually used for partially updating a resource. Post is perfectly acceptable for taking information and adding it to a database. Id say Get is even acceptable as well if you're returning information back to the user.

Comment: I think Nicholas is right. I would suggest him to translate his comment into an answer..

Comment: @MattiaRasulo will do

Comment: Why not refactor your code such that the request logic and the scraping logic are seperated, and then use a proper cronjob to execute the scraping part?

Comment: @NicoHaase Thank you, great suggestion! I hadn't heard of cron jobs before so I will look into it. Seems more convenient than having to trigger a public api endpoint repeated times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A POST request is perfectly acceptable for uploading content to a database. PATCH is usually reserved for when you are partially updating and item. So if you are just updating stuff in your database with this request, then don't hesitate to use PATCH. If you are completely replacing the resource in the database though (or you require the entire resource in the HTTP request, not just the modified stuff), then I'd recommend using PUT instead.

A GET request would be acceptable as well in this situation if you were returning data to the user.

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up!